# Импорт структуры из соседнего файла в Rust

Tags: rust

Структура проекта:

```
src
--main.rs
--settings.rs
```

// settings.rs

```
 pub struct Settings {
        pub SERVER_PORT: u32
    }
```

//main.rs

```
use crate::settings::Settings;

 fn main() {
      let settings = Settings{123};
      println!("Hello, world!");
 }
```

В итоге получаю ошибку "*could not find `settings` in the crate root"*

Через mod я могу получить доступ к структуре, но я не хочу каждый раз указывать область видимости.

```
mod settings

let settings = settings::Settings{123};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо просто сделать и то и другое:

```
mod settings;
use crate::settings::Settings;
```